# Excel SUMIF Offset

Tags: excel, offset

I have a spreadsheet that is used for inventory planning.  It has, in columns, 5 weeks (per month) followed by a month total, then another 5 weeks, followed by another month total, and so on for 12 months.  Each week column is labelled "Wk 1", "Wk 2" and so on.  Each Month is labelled as "Jan", "Feb" and so on.

I have the product code at cell A2, and a lead time (in weeks) at cell C2.  The lead time varies by product.

Column B is the first column with data (column A is used for labels).

On row 5 there is opening stock on hand.
On row 6 there is the sales forecast.
On row 7 there are Purchase Orders received.
On row 8 is closing stock on hand.

Row 10 is a staging area.  This is my problem row.  These are my planned orders.

My cell B10 formula is  =SUM(B6:OFFSET(B6,0,C2-1)).  My planned purchase order = planned sales for the next x weeks, so I need to exclude the month columns.

The result should be as shown in cell B11.  Formula for that cell is =SUM(B6:F6)+SUM(H6:K6)+SUM(N6:R6).  Note that cell L6 is excluded.

Not sure how to increase the number of columns to include in the offset as a lead time may be 26 weeks, so there could be a few "month" columns I need to exclude, and then how to exclude the monthly totals?

I'm thinking maybe using a Sumif combined with Offset, but I am scratching my head.

Your help will be much appreciated.

[Image of Excel file showing structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qt37z.jpg)

Havent tried anything, as am unsure what to try.

Answer (score 0):

see attached photo for your answer.

The formula you seek for cell B10 is:
=SUMIFS(OFFSET(B6,0,0,1,C2+(COUNTA(B4:ZZ4)-COUNTIF(B4:ZZ4,"wk*")+COUNTIF(B3:ZZ3,"exclude"))),OFFSET(B4,0,0,1,C2+(COUNTA(B4:ZZ4)-COUNTIF(B4:ZZ4,"wk*")+COUNTIF(B3:ZZ3,"exclude"))),"=wk*")

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv5eH.png)

Comment: Thanks for that.  Its very close, but does not always work.  If the cell value c2 is say 5 (ie before the exclude column), the answer is incorrect.